# SQL Server stored procedure or alternative method to restart SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, service, sql-agent

There are [various](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/start-stop-or-pause-the-sql-server-agent-service?view=sql-server-2017) [ways](https://www.virtual-dba.com/sql-server-services/) to restart the SQL Server Agent on a server, but I would like to do it from a stored procedure in one of my databases (on the same server). How would one go about doing that? Is there some sort of a system stored procedure that I could call? Or would I need to call some sort of third party library/external language to accomplish that such [as the following](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/672ddc58-c222-45a1-8d7d-1e96a630481c/execute-powershell-function-within-tsql?forum=sqldataaccess)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently one of my co-workers had already solved this:

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'STOP',N'SQLServerAGENT';

-- Give the service a little time to stop
waitfor delay '00:00:10.000'

EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'START',N'SQLServerAGENT';
```

Not sure this the best solution, but should work for my purposes...

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell could be a good approach depending on the circumstances.  the Start-Service and Restart-Service commands would be a good starting point :O